# How can we create a image component in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem

create a image component in AEM 6.1, so that I can able to load the image and display.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking out the Out of the Box 'Image' Component already?

`/libs/foundation/components/image`

This enables you to drag and drop images and display. It can be customized as you wish